# Dynamic table positioning

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here I got some tables:

[image: Valid XHTML].

I would like for them to be dynamicly positioned so in this case for example the number 3 table should be below table 2 leaving no blank space.

Is it possible? How can I get this thing done?

Comment: What are the situations where the table would change positions? If you place tables 1,2, and 3 in 1 column, they will stack how you want them,

Comment: It has to be complete dynamic because all the tables can be very big or very small depending on the client.

Comment: Set up a bootply with the above table format and people will try to help you: http://www.bootply.com/new#

Comment: How are you aligning the tables?

Answer (score 2):

Simplest method is to just use CSS floats (http://jsbin.com/xibuwaso/2/edit). To an extent that will arrange the tables as best as possible into the available space. It isn't perfect; but it is a simple, solution.

A better, more complex, solution is to use something like [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) or [Masonary.js](http://masonry.desandro.com/). Both these Javascript libraries are excellent and have a lot of features and options. Do note, that, depending on the options set, they can rearrange the order of the tables (not the rows within the tables, just the tables themselves); not sure if that is an issue.

Comment: Thank you very much, masonry did the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using float. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3S37c/1/

```
float:left
```

But maybe you can have some issues depending on complexity of your css.

There are some JS libs that do the work.